# error when I try to activate my code navicat 12

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle, navicat

I have an error when I try to activate my code.
and I do not know what's the solution.
This is my error :

[error navicat](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R9YFy.png)

I had already followed youtube videos to activate navicat 12 and I managed normally I had to activate for 2 years, and now after 1 month only he asks me to re-activate my license, the problem is that I have to deliver my project in 4 days and I still have work to do the shots navicat activation is obligatory to continue my work!

Please help me !!!

Comment: Have you contacted their support?

Comment: yes I have it already contacted but no answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think support will help you pirate their products.

Generally speaking if a keygen doesn't work then it's either a virus/spyware or it's not applicable to your version. Ideally you want to try it on a sandbox before using it on your actually system.

It would appear Navicat has na Academic Partner Program for Students which gives you an 1-year free NFR Navicat Premium Non-Commercial licenses. Have a look at the link below:

https://www.navicat.com/en/sponsorship/education/student

Comment: no problems, if you found the answer helpful please up vote or mark the question as answered.